# Где находится C# компилятор последней версии?

Tags: c#

Ребят, я тут хочу с помощью команды `Console.WriteLine()` вывести слово вместе с интерполяции строки.
О чём я имею виду:

```
Using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = "Artem";
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}!");
    }
}
```

Всё работает если запустить проект через **Microsoft Visual Studio**. Также нормально компилирует **Developer Prompt**.

Но путь компилятора:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe

пишет: `Не предвиденный символ "$"`

Какой компилятор использует **Visual Studio** и **Developer Prompt**, и где находится этот компилятор, скажите пж!

Мой

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise

P.s.: не пишите что нужен **C# компилятор** *6.0* или *5.0*, я знаю. И также не пишите про путь

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe

Спасибо!

Мой полный код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = "Artem";
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107826/discussion-on-question-by-mr-catyt---c---).

Answer (score 5):

Не уверен, что все еще актуально для автора, но корректный ответ все же нужен.

Нельзя путать версию компилятора и версию **синтаксиса языка**. Версия компилятора в вашем случае значения не имеет, а вот версия синтаксиса, судя по тексту вопроса, очень даже имеет, т.к. именно от версии синтаксиса зависит поддержка тех или иных конструкций языка в тексте компилируемой программы.

Для того чтобы указать конкретную версию синтаксиса компилятору, используется специальный ключ для консольного компилятора csc.exe:  [-langversion](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/langversion-compiler-option). В документации есть полный список доступных на данный момент версий синтаксиса, который также можно получить во встроенной справке самого компилятора по ключу /? или -?.

Учтите, что в стандартной поставке .NET Framework, компилятор умеет работать только с версиями синтаксиса C# до 5.0 включительно, для поддержки более новых версий, которые еще не стандартизованы, нужно будет более детально ознакомиться с документацией и добавить все необходимое, например компилятор Roslyn, или перейти с .NET Framework на .NET Core, возможно есть и другие варианты, глубоко не копал.

Либо оформить код в виде проекта, в нем указать версию синтаксиса и воспользоваться утилитой MSBuild.exe, которая также входит как в стандартную поставку .NET Framework (с большой вероятностью будет использовать компилятор из стандартной поставки), так и может быть установлена вместе с MS VisualStudio или пакетом SDK (будет использовать более актуальную версию из пакета SDK), может быть запущена из консоли и выполнит все необходимое в автоматическом режиме. Ей потребуется, в простейшем случае, только указать что собирать и куда складывать. Вариант с MSBuild мне кажется более простым, понятным, а потому более предпочтительным. Ну если конечно вашей целью не является изучение редко используемых возможностей компилятора, вроде модульных сборок и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

В .NET Core ушли от одного предустановленного в системную компилятора, теперь каждый SDK включает в себя свою версию csc, с поддержкой соответствующей версии C#.

Путь к SDK можно получить вызовом

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

CSC теперь идет в виде dll, которую нужно запускать вызовом dotnet.

Для SDK 5.0.100, например, полный вызов выглядит как

```
dotnet "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll"
```

Но лучше не дергать компилятор напрямую, а использовать build tools (тот же dotnet).

Answer (score 0):

Следует различать .NET Framework и .NET Core . Версии .NET Framework 5.0 нет, последняя версия .NET Framework 4.8 , которая вышла в 2019г. Есть версия .NET Core 5, она в отличие от .NET Framework кроссплатформенная. Компилятора .NET Core нет, есть сама .NET Core по пути C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe . Для создания консольного проекта в ней используется команда dotnet new console Для компиляции кода в C# можно воспользоваться командой C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe run . Сама же .NET Core 5 лежит по пути C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.104 , но он зависит от версии.

Ответ на вопрос: **Компилятора .Net версии 5.0 и.т.д нет.**

PashaPash, приведите пример компиляции какого либо кода, желательно пример автора вопроса.